# Can I optimize this SQL remote update?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2000

I have this sql update statement which updates a remote table.  Is there any way I can optimize/speed up this code?  It is running as part of a stored procedure.

```
DECLARE @WIP Table(Item varchar(25), WIP int)

--Get Work In Progress Numbers
INSERT INTO @WIP
select (UPC.ItemPrefix + '-' + UPC.ItemCode) As Item, SUM(PO.Quantity) As WIP
--into #WIP
from [NCLGS].[dbo].[AL_ItemUPCs] UPC
INNER JOIN al_PO PO ON PO.UPCID = UPC.UPCID
where PO.status in ('Assigned', 'New', 'UnAssigned', 'WaitingForFile')
Group by  (UPC.ItemPrefix + '-' + UPC.ItemCode)

--SLOW PART, takes over 17 minutes
UPDATE [Server].[Database].[dbo].[Item]  
SET     QtyOnHand = IH.QtyOnHand,
        QtyWorkInProgress = W.WIP   
FROM Avanti_InventoryHeader IH
INNER JOIN [Server].[Database].[dbo].[Item] I ON I.ItemNumber = IH.ItemNumber
LEFT JOIN @WIP W ON IH.ItemNumber = W.Item
WHERE isnumeric(left(IH.ItemNumber, 2)) = 0
```

Comment: How many records you estimate are usually going to be in the @wip table?

Comment: @Jose Chama - 531 last time I ran it.  Will grow very slowly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the real problem with the query, it was updating thousands of records, even if those records didn't change.  So I queried for the changed records, saved that in a table variable, and only updated the changed records.  Entire procedure (not just this part) went from 16min 44sec to 1min 26 sec.

```
--BEGIN EXPERIMENTAL ITEM UPDATE SECTION
    DECLARE @WIP Table(Item varchar(25), WIP int)

    --Get Work In Progress Numbers
    INSERT INTO @WIP
    select (UPC.ItemPrefix + '-' + UPC.ItemCode) As Item, SUM(PO.Quantity) As WIP
    --into #WIP
    from [NCLGS].[dbo].[AL_ItemUPCs] UPC
    INNER JOIN al_PO PO ON PO.UPCID = UPC.UPCID
    where PO.status in ('Assigned', 'New', 'UnAssigned', 'WaitingForFile')
    Group by  (UPC.ItemPrefix + '-' + UPC.ItemCode)

    Declare @Remote Table(Item varchar(25), QtyOnHand int, WIP int)

    INSERT INTO @REMOTE
    Select ItemNumber, QtyOnHand, QtyWorkInProgress
    from [BMPR.COM].[NCL-CustomerPortal].[dbo].[Item]

    DECLARE @ItemsToUpdate Table (Item varchar(50))

    INSERT INTO @ItemsToUpdate
    Select R.Item
    From @Remote R
    Inner join Avanti_InventoryHeader IH ON R.Item = IH.ItemNumber
    LEFT JOIN @WIP W ON R.Item = W.Item
    Where R.QtyOnHand <> IH.QtyOnHand 
    OR R.WIP <> W.WIP

    --Select * from @ItemsToUpdate

    UPDATE [BMPR.COM].[NCL-CustomerPortal].[dbo].[Item]  
    SET     QtyOnHand = IH.QtyOnHand,
            QtyWorkInProgress = W.WIP   
    FROM Avanti_InventoryHeader IH
    INNER JOIN [BMPR.COM].[NCL-CustomerPortal].[dbo].[Item] I ON I.ItemNumber = IH.ItemNumber
    LEFT JOIN @WIP W ON IH.ItemNumber = W.Item
    WHERE I.ItemNumber in ( Select * from @ItemsToUpdate )
--END EXPERIMENTAL ITEM UPDATE SECTION
```

Any comments on this method?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem in the past and I had to use dynamic SQL to increase the performance.

I found out that when I joined the local temp table with the remote table SQL was bringing all the data to the local server and then filtering what I had in the where statement.

In this case I would try to pass the whole variable table @WIP as a nested table using SELECT UNION ALL in a dynamic query.

I am talking about something like this:

```
 DECLARE @WIP Table(Item varchar(25), WIP int)

    --Get Work In Progress Numbers
    INSERT INTO @WIP
    select (UPC.ItemPrefix + '-' + UPC.ItemCode) As Item, SUM(PO.Quantity) As WIP
    --into #WIP
    from [NCLGS].[dbo].[AL_ItemUPCs] UPC
    INNER JOIN al_PO PO ON PO.UPCID = UPC.UPCID
    where PO.status in ('Assigned', 'New', 'UnAssigned', 'WaitingForFile')
    Group by  (UPC.ItemPrefix + '-' + UPC.ItemCode)

declare @SQL VARCHAR(MAX)

set @SQL = '
UPDATE [Server].[Database].[dbo].[Item]  
SET     QtyOnHand = IH.QtyOnHand,
        QtyWorkInProgress = W.WIP   
FROM Avanti_InventoryHeader IH
INNER JOIN [Server].[Database].[dbo].[Item] I 
    ON I.ItemNumber = IH.ItemNumber
LEFT JOIN ('

select @SQL = @SQL + 'select '''+w.Item+''' as Item, 
    '''+cast( w.WIP as varchar(50))+''' as WIP union all '
from @WIP W

set @SQL = @SQL + ' select NULL,0 ) W   
    ON IH.ItemNumber = W.Item
WHERE isnumeric(left(IH.ItemNumber, 2)) = 0 '

PRINT @SQL
```

**It does not look very neat, but it might work for you as it did for me.**

Comment: -I'm not sure how that would help?  Does dynamic SQL not parse the query then do exactly the same thing?

Comment: In my case I needed to retrieve a few thousand rows from the remote server and I joined a temp table with what I needed. Then I found that it was bringing the whole table (that is what I think your update is doing right now), so I created a dynamic SQL with a IN in the where with all the IDs I needed to retrieve. I know is not very nice, but it decreased the time to milliseconds.

Comment: -I'm still not understanding.

Comment: I just added some code to show you what I am talking about. Basically you will be passing the whole variable table @wip as a "select union all" nested table to the remote server.

Comment: What does the Union all do here?

Comment: It is like a UNION but it performs better because it does not run a distinct. Check this article: http://bit.ly/oD6gtL

Comment: @MAW74656 let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1379/discussion-between-jose-chama-and-maw74656)

Comment: Also, did you mean to concatenate the last literal onto the end of @SQL?  Looks like we're just replacing here.

Comment: Love the concept, but can't do it all at once with the varchar limit of 8000 in SQL-Server 2000.  I'm investigating other options, but will certainly keep this one in mind.

Answer (score 1):

I'd try loading the items into a local table variable first before doing the join.

```
DECLARE @WIP Table ( Item varchar(25), WIP int )
  --Get Work In Progress Numbers 
INSERT  INTO @WIP
        select  ( UPC.ItemPrefix + '-' + UPC.ItemCode ) As Item,
                SUM(PO.Quantity) As WIP 
        --into #WIP 
        from    [NCLGS].[dbo].[AL_ItemUPCs] UPC
                INNER JOIN al_PO PO ON PO.UPCID = UPC.UPCID
        where   PO.status in ( 'Assigned', 'New', 'UnAssigned',
                               'WaitingForFile' )
        Group by ( UPC.ItemPrefix + '-' + UPC.ItemCode )  

DECLARE @Item TABLE (ItemNumber  INT PRIMARY KEY, QtyOnHand INT)
SELECT ItemNumber, QtyOnHand
FROM   [Server].[Database].[dbo].[Item]    

--SLOW PART, takes over 17 minutes 
UPDATE  [Server].[Database].[dbo].[Item]
SET     QtyOnHand = IH.QtyOnHand,
        QtyWorkInProgress = W.WIP
FROM    Avanti_InventoryHeader IH
        INNER JOIN @item I ON I.ItemNumber = IH.ItemNumber
        LEFT JOIN @WIP W ON IH.ItemNumber = W.Item
WHERE   isnumeric(left(IH.ItemNumber, 2)) = 0
```

Additionally you could consider further further restricting the update by removing records from the table variable that aren't being updated and join only the updated records to the linked server.

```
DECLARE @Item TABLE
    (
      ItemNumber INT PRIMARY KEY,
      QtyOnHand INT,
      updated BIT DEFAULT ( 0 ),
      WIP int
    )
SELECT  ItemNumber,
        QtyOnHand
FROM    [Server].[Database].[dbo].[Item] 

UPDATE  i
SET     i.QtyOnHand = ih.QtyOnHand,
        updated = 1
FROM    @item i
        INNER JOIN Avanti_InventoryHeader IH ON I.ItemNumber = IH.ItemNumber
        LEFT JOIN @WIP W ON IH.ItemNumber = W.Item
WHERE   isnumeric(left(IH.ItemNumber, 2)) = 0  

DELETE FROM @item WHERE updated = 0

UPDATE  I
SET     QtyOnHand = IH.QtyOnHand,
        QtyWorkInProgress = IH.WIP
FROM    [Server].[Database].[dbo].[Item] I
        INNER JOIN @item IH ON I.ItemNumber = IH.ItemNumber
```

Comment: -But how will SQL know which rows in Item to update if I"m not joining to it?

Comment: -I'm sure I'm just missing it, but your first example updates the remote table without joining to it, and your second example up dates the remote table BY JOINING to it.  Is one of those a mistake?

Comment: First I pull the whole table from the remote server into a table variable.  Then do all the work on the table variable. When I'm done I write back to the remote table by joining to the pre-processed and potentially smaller data set.  Maybe it'll help..Not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a stored procedure on the remote server that is called by this stored procedure.

In the remote stored procedure, pull the data that you need onto the remote server into temporary tables.  Then perform the UPDATE / JOIN on the remote server.

In my experience, trying to do a join across a linked server can be very slow... and it is often faster to get all the required data on one server or the other before doing any joining.

Comment: -I'm not sure if they'll let me put a sproc on the remote server (its not ours), but I may have to try.

Answer (score -1):

There is an ONLY clause in PostgreSQL's UPDATE that will only update the table mentioned. Otherwise it tries to update all the tables you're joining and that could be where the bottleneck is. What type of SQL are you using? If it is Postgres, are possibly some others, try changing the update line to

```
UPDATE ONLY [Server].[Database].[dbo].[Item]
```